# Вызов subprocess в цикле

Tags: python, циклы, subprocess

Друзья, есть код:

```
_def main():_  
    _name_script = "-S\"read_header.py\""  
    _name_i64 = "RawFile.i64"  
    subprocess.call(["idaq64", _name_script, _name_i64])
```

Вопрос: как мне сделать так чтобы можно было передавать в качестве аргументов список элементов?

Проблема заключается в том, что не получается сделать правильный формат. Должно быть:

```
_name_script = "-S\"**хрень которая будет меняться, например 1.py, потом 2.py**""
```

а вот как загнать эти самые 1.py, 2.py в эту строку я и не могу понять.

Comment: Вам необходимо, проходя циклом по списку, вызывать `subprocess` с одним элементом, или же сформировать одну строку аргументов из списка?

Comment: Во-первых - спасибо что откликнулись.
Задача была проходить по списку и вызывать subprocess. Собственно я затупил из-за того, что давно не юзал питон. А делается это простым форматированием строки - уже допер)

Comment: вопрос неясный. Какую команду вы хотите получить? Покажите на примере 1.py, 2.py как это в командной строчке выглядит. Не ясно, что у вас `_def` в коде делает. Зачем вы кавычки внутрь имени добавили. Кавычки обычно shell обратывает, но subprocess не вызывает shell, если явно не попросите. Вы хотели, `subprocess.check_call(['idaq64', '-S', 'read_header.py', name_i64])` вызвать?

Comment: Вы правы. Именно это я и хотел сделать. Просто запамятовал.